# How to do scanner exception in Java?

Tags: java, validation, parsing, java.util.scanner

I would like to scan a float and an integer. I want to add an exception, if the scanned number is not a float or int, scan again while the input number is not correct. I tried with `hasNextFloat` and `hasNextInt` but I didn't really got it right.

```
package has_exception;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Has_Exception {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a float!");
        float fl = scn.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int a = scn.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: **How** did you use `hasNextFloat` and `hasNextInt`?

Comment: Remember that when using hasNextFloat. The input isn't actually read. So you would need to check if the next bit of input is a float. And then read is anyway and repeat untill you get a float

Answer (score 1):

try with a parse of string into a float and do this until the user gives a valid input...
the initial values of the float will  depend of your application, and you can repeat this approach for the integer value

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    float fl = -1.0f;

    while (fl < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a float!");

        String x = scn.nextLine();
        try {
            fl = Float.parseFloat(x);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a float");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should do this with a boolean to check if the float is correct. Otherwise, you can't enter a negative value. And yes, you mention that the initial value depends on the application, but sometimes you want to be able to enter any kind of float.

Comment: that is what i meant with the comment about the initial value of the float... is fl is valid only when is positive then my suggestion is ok... OP must clarifies..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do{..}while()` with `nextLine()` instead, for example :

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean correct = true;
do {
    try {

        System.out.println("Enter a float!");
        float fl = Float.parseFloat(scn.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        correct = false;
    }
} while (!correct);

scn.close();//close your scanner
```

Comment: almost the same idea :) how not to uV!